# Hibernate, keeping a reference to "parent" object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have very little experience with hibernate, so this is probably a proper newbie question:

To keep this question simple, let's say I have two types of objects, family and person. One family consists of several people.

If I have a one-to-many relationship defined on family towards person, then the relation between the two would be contained within the person table, as a foreign key. I would then assume that adding people to the family, and then saving the family object, would be enough to get that relationship into the database. This does not seem to be the case, however.

What I currently have to do is:

1) Add the mentioned one-to-many relationship on the family, which gives me the necessary methods to add or remove people to the family object.

2) Add a many-to-one relationship on the person object to the family, which makes it possible for me to reference the family from the person.

3) I then proceed to add this person object, with the manually set family reference, to a family object. Then I save the family object.

This just seems really cumbersome and wrong. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Family` to `Person` is one to many relationship  , `Family` class should have a collection property (eg , A List) to hold the collection of its `Person` .

You can encapsulate the process of setting the references between `Family` and `Person` when adding a `Person` to a `Family` in a method ,for example , a method called `addPerson()`.Your `Family` and `Person` class looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Family{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="family")
    private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void addPerson(Person personToAdd){
        this.personList.add(personToAdd);
        personToAdd.setFamily(this);
    }

   /**getter and setter**/
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Person{

    @JoinColumn(name="family_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Family family;

    /**getter and setter**/

}
```

Then for adding a Person to an existing family (ID=1) :

```
session.beginTransaction();
Family  family = (Family)session.get(Family.class, 1);   
Person person = new Person();
person.set(xxxx);   
family.addPerson(person);  
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in what you are doing, it is called as **inverse mapping**. It is even logically correct.

In **Person.java**

```
Family family;
```

In **Family.java**

```
List<Persons> familyMembers; //or any other collection.
```

If do not need an inverse reference for **Family** on **Person** you can remove it. You can try an example [here](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html).

Comment: The problem is I don't know if I need the inverse reference for `Family` on `Person`.

I thought maybe the one-to-many from `Family` to `Person` would be enough to populate the foreign key in `Person`, but that is not the behavior I'm getting. Whenever I persist a `Family` with one or more new people in it, the foreign key is simply set to null in the db, thus the relationship between the two is not persisted.